# XSL variable doesn't pull in value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this xslt file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"
        omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="desc" select="//myNode[@objectId='desc']/@select" />
    <xsl:variable name="largeImage" 
          select="//myNode[@objectId='largeImage']/@select" />

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:value-of select="$largeImage" />          
        <xsl:value-of select="$desc" />

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this xml:

```
<root>
    <myNode type="popup" link="image" label="Large Image:"
        objectId="largeImage" customAttribute="No" />  
    <myNode type="editor" label="Description:" objectId="desc" required="yes"/>
</root>
```

For some reason, the variable works for displaying the value of `desc`, but not `largeImage`.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong in my XSLT?

Comment: Neither one should work. You don't have a `@select` attribute on either of those `<myNode>` elements.

Comment: Downvoting, because as Mads says, it's clear you're not describing the problem you actually encountered.

Answer (score 0):

What's the expected result?  If you want to display "Large Image:" and "Description:", this would work:

```
<xsl:variable name="desc" select="//myNode[@objectId='desc']/@label" />
<xsl:variable name="largeImage" 
              select="//myNode[@objectId='largeImage']/@label" />
```